# If I find the answer to a question I'm writing, should I still post it?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions

I'm currently writing a question and I've come across a similar question with a suitable answer. Should I still post my question that might get marked as a duplicate?

Comment: Generally speaking, no. Unless you are extremely certain that a new signpost is really needed to arrive to that duplicate. But is generally best to leave those to arise naturally. Enough inadvertent dupes are asked each minute to start asking dupes intentionally.

Comment: Depends mostly on how hard you looked to find it. If you worked really hard at finding it, and it didn't pop up for any of the obvious search terms, then it would probably add value to have a duplicate signpost to help future users find it. If you know in your heart that you were lazy about searching (and we all are sometimes), then there's probably no point in having another duplicate lying around. Alternatively, if you can frame your problem differently and post an answer that *adds value*, while still giving proper credit to the existing answer you based it off of, that might be worth doing